# How to get user selected text in SwiftUI TextEditor

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui

I have this code and I need to get user-selected text from TextEditor. How do I do such a thing in SwiftUI?

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    @Binding var document: AppDocument

    var body: some View {
        TextEditor(text: $document.text)
            .disableAutocorrection(true)
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and see: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). What have you tried in SwiftUI? This is not a code writing service.

Answer (score 5):

While added in iOS 15 `.textSelection` modifier enables the end-user of an app to select and copy text, it doesn't help the developer obtain *user-selected text* or range of selection. I don't think that, as of early 2022, there is a way to do it natively in SwiftUI.

However, UIKit's `UITextView` has `selectedRange` property, and `UITextViewDelegate` has `textViewDidChangeSelection(_:)` method that fires off every time the user changes the selection. To use that in SwiftUI, we need to build a bridge using `UIViewRepresentable` protocol like so:

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var text = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        UITextViewRepresentable(text: $text)
    }
}

struct UITextViewRepresentable: UIViewRepresentable {
    let textView = UITextView()
    @Binding var text: String
    
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UITextView {
        textView.delegate = context.coordinator
        return textView
    }
    
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UITextView, context: Context) {
        // SwiftUI -> UIKit
        uiView.text = text
    }
    
    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        Coordinator(text: $text)
    }
    
    class Coordinator: NSObject, UITextViewDelegate {
        @Binding var text: String
        
        init(text: Binding<String>) {
            self._text = text
        }
        
        func textViewDidChange(_ textView: UITextView) {
            // UIKit -> SwiftUI
            _text.wrappedValue = textView.text
        }
        
        func textViewDidChangeSelection(_ textView: UITextView) {
            // Fires off every time the user changes the selection.
            print(textView.selectedRange)
        }
    }
}
```