# SwiftUI: How to use .textSelectability to store a word from a multi-word string (using .contextMenu)

Tags: ios, swift, string, swiftui, text

This is my code below:

```
@State private var selectedWord: String

Text("Hello my friend, how do you do?")
    .textSelection(.enabled)
    .contextMenu {
        Button("Option 1") {
            print(selectedWord)
        }
        .foregroundColor(.red)
        .font(.title)
    }
```

What I would like to do is be able to store the specific word selected by the user and then print it out to the console when a button is pushed, after the contextMenu pops up. I'm not sure how to capture the specific word... there must be a way for it as the default for contextMenu is 'copy' and 'share'..so the word is being stored somewhere?

Thanks for your help.

My thought process is to pass a binding to .contextMenu but not sure how to get that initial string out of the Text() view.

Comment: This isn't possible with native SwiftUI, at least not using `.textSelection.` According to Apple's docs you cannot use text selection to select individual words, only the entire `Text` struct. Doc: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/textselection(_:). Instead, consider looking into a UIView like this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71121355/20422552